# Matlab: Apply function on struct matrix

Tags: function, matlab, matrix, struct, apply

I have a matrix of structs:

```
s(1:2,1:3) = struct('a',1,'b',2);
```

I have a function that has 2 int inputs, and calculates an int values according
to some logic. How can I Apply the function on all the matrix s using the fields of each struct ('a' and 'b') as input for the function. The result matrix should be the same size as s just with the result of the function as data.

```
function f = SomeFunctionIWrote(a,b)
    %...Some calculations...
    f = result;
 end
```

Thanks,
Guy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying the same function to each element of an array is what [arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) is built for (see [this blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/11/24/working-with-arrays-of-structures/) by Loren Shure for a helpful discussion/example).

If `f` is your function and `s` is an array of structures with fields `a` and `b`,

```
result = arrayfun(@(x)f(x.a,x.b), s);
```

will do the trick. `@(x)` is an [anonymous function](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2012/08/29/thoughts-about-anonymous-functions/) if you haven't come across those before.

If the function doesn't return a scalar, use the `'uniformoutput'` option (set to `false`) so that `result` becomes a cell array.

```
result = arrayfun(@(x)f(x.a,x.b), s, 'uniformoutput', false);
```

---

Note 1: `arrayfun` is slow! Often (always?) slower than a loop. The advantage of it (in my experience/opinion) comes from not having to deal with size/shape of matrix dimensions if/when your code changes, and shorter code that is easier to read.

Note 2: you can use `'uni'` and `0` in place of `'uniformoutput'` and `false` to save typing/line space, though at the expense of clarity